# strange behaviour with css grid plus media querys

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

I am trying to make a responsive grid section using media queries and CSS grid. The grid looks fine on full width but as soon as 999px and 750px media queries kick in I begin to have a strange problem where I have extra CSS grid gutters on the right and on the bottom of the grid.

```css
.categories-grid > .website-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "nails nails offers offers"
    "image image kids-img kids"
    "image image hair hair-img";
  gap: 40px 35px;
  height: 1060px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) .categories-grid > .website-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nails nails"
    "kids-img kids"
    "hair hair-img"
    "offers offers";
  gap: 30px 25px;
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) .categories-grid > .website-grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "nails"
    "offers"
    "kids-img"
    "kids"
    "hair-img"
    "hair";
}
```

[max750px media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKDb5.png)

[max999px media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh1sN.png)

[full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl1DF.png)

Comment: Look up  the syntax for media queries. You seem to be missing some curly brackets. If you still have a problem then please correct the code in your question and make a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: I did not notice that thanks for pointing it out but that is the output from the browser inspector. my media queries are formatted properly in my CSS file so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The "image" div was causing an extra row to be created. after making a css rule to hide that div in the media queries the extra rows and columns went away.